# Mangento check customer if exists

Tags: magento2, customer

I need to load the customer by using the customer repository to check if this customer is existing I used dependency injection in the controller but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me?
Many thanks

```
 namespace ThuyNT\SSO\Controller\Account;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
 {

protected $resultPageFactory;


public function __construct(
    Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepo)
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->customerRepo = $customerRepo;
    parent::__construct($context);
}


public function execute()
{
    try{
        $customerId =1;
          $customer =  $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
          return $customer;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        return $this->_messageManager->addError('failed');
    
}
```

}

Comment: please paste your code in question and also let me know what you facing error?

Comment: i updated my code above, thanks for your help

Comment: Do you already have customer_id? You just need to check id(i.e. customer) already exist or not?

Comment: i used default customer id of Magento2 and i just need to check if this id exist or not

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
 public function __construct(
        Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepo){
        $this->customerRepo = $customerRepo;
    }
```

And your code check customer exist:

```
$customer = $this->customerRepo->getById('your customer id');
if($customer){
      //process your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following in you Constructor:-

```
     protected $_customer;
    protected $_customerFactory;
```

```
public function __construct(...
                            \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
                            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customers
)
{
    ...
    $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
    $this->_customer = $customers;
}
```

for collection :-

```
$this->_customer->getCollection()
               ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
               ->load()
```

For filter collection:-

```
$this->_customerFactory->create()->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                ->addAttributeToFilter("firstname", array("eq" => "Arun"))
                -load()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject the following

```php
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
) {
    $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
}
```

Load by ID

```php
   /**
     * Get customer by Id.
     *
     * @param int $customerId
     *
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer
     */
    public function getById($customerId)
    {
        try {
            return $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            return false;
        }  
    }
```

Load by Email

```php
   /**
     * Get customer by email.
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer
     */
    public function getByEmail($email)
    {
        try {
            return $this->customerRepositoryInterface->get($email);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e);
            return false;
        }  
    }
```

Class to look at

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/app/code/Magento/Customer/Api/CustomerRepositoryInterface.php

Comment: which class should i put this code? thanks for your help

Comment: I recommend you create your own helper.  Then load helper in controller.